# Need to join two tables in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to join the two tables. But not quite understand which join statement need to use.
LEFT, RIGHT, INNER and OUTER JOIN

Table_A

| group_id | user_id | protocal_id | file_id | file_name | direction | mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | TCP001 | TCP_File001 | file001 | 1 | Active |

Table_B

| group_id | user_id | file_id | limit_s | limit_e | apgroup_id | ap_id | snd_rcv_mode | file_cate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | TCP_File001 | 13:00:00 | 13:30:00 | GOG001 | GO001 | Auto | Text |

The output should be like this

| group_id | user_id | protocal_id | file_id | file_name | direction | mode | limit_s | limit_e | apgroup_id | ap_id | snd_rcv_mode | file_cate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A001 | TCP001 | TCP_File001 | file001 | 1 | Active | 13:00:00 | 13:30:00 | GOG001 | GO001 | Auto | Text |

Comment: Shown example does not allow to understand what joining type is needed. What if table B does not contain a row matched the row in table A? and for backward case?

Comment: You need to explain what behavior you're expecting and what you've tried. StackOverflow is a site where you can ask for help or clarification on specific questions when you're stuck. This means, we expect that you've already done some research or tried other solutions around the internet.

Comment: can you share your coding attempt at this problem and the output you got?

Comment: Try them all, see what suits, baffled why you would ask.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*,b.*
FROM Table_A as a
INNER JOIN Table_B as b ON a.group_id = b.group_id
```